# For the sake of completeness

Tags: discussion

I feel having a stage/progress based discussion would always be a better approach to think of all these Q&As/discussions in this site.

For example, have some thing like NEW state when question is posted, as it gets answered/viewed/commented, it moves into different "STATES" of Progress state machine and finally, Q&A would be CLOSED.

Comment: "This site is all **[about]** getting answers. **It's not a discussion forum**..."

Comment: An active question doesn't have a progress; it's either Answered or Unanswered.

Answer (score 6):

This is already here, implicitly. The states you refer to probably map to these situations:

- "NEW" == unanswered (and possibly also "recent")
- "...." == has answers and/or is active, but no accepted answer
- "CLOSED" == answered and accepted answer

My mapping may not be accurate for your taste, so some of the "states" you'd like to have will have no 1-on-1 equivalent thing on SE. However, the point is that most of these "states" do have an analogous thing on SE, so I don't think any change is necessary.

There's a distinct visual for those states too by the way, e.g.:

[image: different question states]

The first one is in intermediate state: having answers but none accepted. The second one is a "NEW" question, and the final one is a question that you call "CLOSED"

PS. Note that "[closing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)" has a different meaning on these sites.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing seems to be a very forum-like method for solving a problem.

1. You pose a very vague, incomplete problem
2. Multiple users help you with multiple steps along the way
3. You update your problem as users help you sort through the various issues you are having
4. Repeat Steps 2 & 3 until you've resolved all of your issues
5. You close the question because you don't need help anymore.

The process makes the question and answers all about solving the problem of the original poster.  However, that is not what the Stack Exchange sites are about.  We are about helping everyone solve their programming problems both now and in the future by building up a repository of quality programming problems and solutions.

The idea is that you ask a specific *well-defined* question and get specific answers back.  When you encounter a new issue, you don't change your question (because that would invalidate the answers you already received), but instead you ask another specific question.  The system is designed in such a way that the only real say you get in the future of question<sup>1</sup> is that you can identify which answer helped **you** most by selecting it as the accepted answer.

Questions are never closed because they were solved, they are left so future visitors can provide new answers and users can update existing answers as technologies change.  Closing questions here refers to identifying questions that are off-topic or unclear or are otherwise out of our intended scope to help future visitors find quality answers to their questions and not pollute the site with a lot of noise.

These new or updated answers are not necessarily going to help you in the future (since you already solved your original problem), they will help someone else who has a similar question in the future.

Your idea seems to get away from everything that made Stack Overflow (and the rest of the Stack Exchange sites) great.